# sudo iptables -P OUTPUT DROP not working on manjaro pinephone

Tags: iptables, manjaro

I did:

```
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT DROP
curl example.com # this actually fetches the website, not affected by iptables
```

How can I debug this issue? If I do the same on my linux desktop it the curl will fail.

Comment: What version of Manjaro are you running? What sort of customizations have you perofrmed since installing it? These answers might help us try to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: cat /etc/os-release says "Manjaro ARM". havent done any customization I'm using it as it came in the box.

Comment: is curl going out over IPv6 and not IPv4?

Comment: if I do curl example.com -v it shows an IPv6 address

Comment: If `curl` is connecting to an IPv6 address than your IPv4 firewall rules aren't going to have any impact. You need to use `ip6tables`.

Comment: oh I see, how come on my debian desktop example.com is an ipv4 address and on the manjaro pinephone it's ipv6?

Comment: There are tools available (e.g., [ufw](https://serverfault.com/a/356223/27515)) that will help you manage parallel sets of firewall rules for both IPv4 and IPv6. Apparently I asked that question 10 years ago!

Comment: Are they connected to the same ISP? Maybe there's a difference in how the kernels on the two systems are built, particularly if they're running different Manjaro releases. Not really enough information here to tell, and that's really turning into a different question.

Answer (score 2):

`iptables` only affects IPv4 traffic. There are other protocols; in particular IPv6, which `example.com` has a record for:

```
$ host example.com
example.com has address 93.184.216.34
example.com has IPv6 address 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946
example.com mail is handled by 0 .
```

Therefore, to also affect IPv6 traffic `ip6tables` will need to be called; the command is mostly the same as for `iptables`:

```
sudo ip6tables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

Or, one can use [some system that configures both IPv4 and IPv6 for you](https://serverfault.com/a/356223/27515), or you could try the more modern [nftables](https://www.nftables.org/projects/nftables/index.html), if the system supports that.